# how to capture entered element. CloudFuntions. Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I need to capture the elment that is entered into a certain database, how could I do it? I have tried with `snap.val()` but it does not work for me, with `snap.after.val()` but I am not very clear about its use ....

```
exports.getDat = functions.database.ref('/a_principal').onWrite((snap, context) => {

    // snap.data.val(); fail-
    // snap.val(); fail-

    console.log(snap.before.val());
    console.log(snap.after.val());

});
```

with the use of `snap.before.val()` and `snap.after.val()` I can acpture the value of the string before and after the event, but how do I capture the inserted data? that is, the one that activates the event that in this case would be the last one that appears in `snap.after.val()`

`snap.before.val()` return:
`{ '01': 11, '02': 22, '03': 33 }`

`snap.after.val()` return:
`{ '01': 11, '02': 22, '03': 33, '04': 44 }`

it is evident that the data that activated `.onWrite` was `{ '04': 44 }`. That is the data that I want to create, how could I do it?

Thanks for the help.

*PS: sorry if my English is bad enough, I use translator :(*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Functions gives you two snapshots:

1. the data as it existed before the write operation that triggered the function
2. the data as is exists after the write operation that triggered the function

The snapshots contain no explicit information on the delta of what has changed. But by comparing the old data and the new data, you can determine that yourself in the code. This is actually a pure JavaScript operation, unrelated to Firebase or Cloud Functions.

A simple way to implement this:

```js
var before = { '01': 11, '02': 22, '03': 33, '05': 0 };
var after =  { '01': 11, '02': 22, '03': 32, '04': 44 };

var added = {},
    removed = {},
    changed = {};
    
Object.keys(before).forEach(function(key) {
  if (!after[key]) {
    removed[key] = before[key];
  }
  else if (before[key] !== after[key]) {
    changed[key] = after[key];
  }
});
Object.keys(after).forEach(function(key) {
  if (!before[key]) added[key] = after[key];
});

console.log("added", added, "removed", removed, "changed", changed);
```

Comment: great, thanks for the clarification, I already have idea how to handle this type of data thanks to your answer, you are very kind. regards!